# how Get MVC Json Result and populate in a Table using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I need an idea on how I can GET my MVC Json result and populate it inside my view table using Ajax,

this is my json result

```
public JsonResult GetAllContacts()
    {

        var User = GetLoggedInUserID();

        var getContact = _contactService.GetUserContacts(User).Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            MobileNumber = x.MobileNumber
        });

        return Json(getContact, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Please how can I archieve this?

Secondly My Table has Checkboxs that I will be able to pick the Mobile number and populate them inside a Listbox

this is my table view

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="contacts">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" name="chooseAllRecipient" id="chooseAllRecipient" /></th>
                                    <th class="center">Contact Name(s)</th>
                                    <th class="center">Mobile Number(s)</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chooseRecipient" class="my_chkBox"></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

and this is my Script

```
function GetContact() {

$.ajax({
    url: table.data('/Contact/GetAllContacts'),
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(),
    cache: false,
    context: table,
    success: function (contact) {
        var tableBody = this.find('tbody');
        tableBody.empty();
        $.each(contact, function (index, contact) {
            $('<tr/>', {
                html: $('<td/>', {
                    html: contact.Name
                }).after($('<td/>', {
                    html: contact.MobileNumber
                }))
            }).appendTo(tableBody);
        });
    },
    error: function () { alert("error"); }
});
```

}

$('#getContacts').click(function () {

```
GetContact();
```

});

please I need some help on how to get this working with jQuery and AJAX because I can't figure out were the problem is coming form please thank you very mush...

Comment: Did you figureout that you are using contact as data parameter and contact as item parameter? It's the same name, it's causing confusion for the function. Change it and see if solves.

Comment: As @Fals said change the `contact.Name` and `contact.MobileNumber` to `this.Name` and `this.MobileNumber`.

Comment: Another question I have is what is **table**?  I'm assuming it's a variable, but I'm guessing you're not show all the javascript code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
public JsonResult GetAllContacts()
{
    var user = GetLoggedInUserID();
    var contacts = _contactService.GetUserContacts(user).Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.Name,
        MobileNumber = x.MobileNumber
    }).ToList(); // <--- cast to list if GetUserContacts returns an IEnumerable
    return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In your view, populate this JSON data into the grid:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="chooseAllRecipient" id="chooseAllRecipient" /></th>
            <th class="center">Contact Name(s)</th>
            <th class="center">Mobile Number(s)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="contacts"></tbody>
 </table>
 <button id="add_recipient">Add Selected Recipients</button>
 <select id="recipientList"></select>
```

**jQuery**

```
function GetContact() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Contact/GetAllContacts",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var row = "";
            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                row+="<tr><td><input type='checkbox'id='"+item.Id+"' name='chooseRecipient' class='my_chkBox' /></td><td>"+item.Name+"</td><td>"+item.MobileNumber+"</td></tr>";
            });
            $("#contacts").html(row);    
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}

$('#getContacts').click(function(){
      GetContact();
});
```

**EDIT:** adding extra requirement for populating mobile numbers from selected checkboxes to listbox

```
$("#add_recipient").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#contacts input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        var contact_number = $(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').text();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#recipientList').append('<option value="'+ id +'">'+ contact_number +'</option>');              
    }).get();        
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/fnCL3/)

Comment: Thank you very mush... now I can populate perfectly... One more thing please, that table has a button that when those checkboxes are selected it should get the mobile number into a listbox... so please can you just complete that for me on that fiddle Demo please God bless you thank you very mush

Comment: Glad it helped. Perhaps you could add a separate question for that?

Comment: `<div class="center"><a class="btn btn-success btn-large" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" id="addRecipientList">Add To Recipient List</a></div>`

this is the list box

`
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRecipient, Model.Recipients, new { id = "recipientList", style = "width: 250px; height: 160px;", name = "recipientList" })
`

Comment: Every thing is okay now Please can I get your email so I can get to you direct 7rippl3m@gmail.com

Comment: Do you mean to remove a number from the list box? You would typically need to first select the option (or do a multiple selection) then click on another button to remove the number.

Comment: No, I mean Checking for existing Number not to repeat it self when adding again...

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy lemon squeezy with this plugin:

https://github.com/jongha/jquery-jsontotable