# How to make the data show by filter in a razor page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The part of the view where I filter it through Car Categories:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
     <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Car Styles</option>
         @foreach (var item in Model.CarCats)
            {
              <option value="@item.CarCategoryID">@item.CarCategoryName</option>
             }
         </select>
       </div>
```

The part of the view where I have cars:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
        {
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="carGalleryWrapper">
                        <div class="carGallery" style="background:url('@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ImagePath)') no-repeat 0 0 ">
                            <div class="carDetails">
                                <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyFee) / Per Day</h4>
                                <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model), Navi, Leather, ABS</h3>
                                <button type="submit" class="driveMore">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Drive Now", "Detail", null, new { id = item.CarID }, htmlAttributes: new {})</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

I want to show the cars of a category when i select it from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few ways of going about this

1. Use a form and populate a new Car list serverside (server side)
   submit the form with the selected category, in your method for handling your form 
   remove cars from your list that dont have that category etc.
   A good example of this is [here](https://nimblegecko.com/using-simple-drop-down-lists-in-ASP-NET-MVC/)
   In the method that takes your page model(the method that will be posted to on form submission) that is where you would filter your car list down by category. Then return the same page.
   This doesnt use js so it will always work even if your user has disabled js in their browser however its not the most user friendly due to the page reloading.
2. Use js to call an api that takes in a category and returns a new list of cars (client and server side)
   Then repopulate your frontend with the new list
   My js isnt by any stretch any good but the rough idea is to create an api controller that will take in your category and return the filtered list.
   look at this answer for a start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407108/how-get-mvc-json-result-and-populate-in-a-table-using-ajax) if you look at the success response of the ajax call, it builds up html and thats what you would need to do with the filtered list returned from the api
3. Use js and css to hide/show cars based on the selected category (client side)

Did you have a preference?

Comment: I don't have a preference for it. But if you could help me out by writing a sample code for this. Many thanks

Comment: ive edited my answer with some examples that should get you on your way